# How to import tensorflow-GPU with AMD graphics card, or any workaround

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I have AMD graphics card with me. Now, when I try to import tensorflow, I get the following error.
I think (as I understand) that if I use normal TF and not TF-GPU, then this issue may resolve. However, I do want to use the graphics card because my reinforcement learning algorithms are really very slow otherwise. Is there any workaround?

> ImportError: Could not find 'nvcuda.dll'. TensorFlow requires that
> this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH%
> environment variable. Typically it is installed in
> 'C:\Windows\System32'. If it is not present, ensure that you have a
> CUDA-capable GPU with the correct driver installed.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, right now with AMD, there are two ways you can go about it.
Either using the lastest AMD's ROCm to install tensorflow.

[official ROCm install](https://rocmdocs.amd.com/en/latest/Installation_Guide/Installation-Guide.html)

and

[official ROCm tensorflow install](https://rocmdocs.amd.com/en/latest/Deep_learning/Deep-learning.html?highlight=tensorflow#tensorflow-installation)

check if you use the supported AMD GPU check it over [here](https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm)

or using the OpenCL implementation of TensorFlow if your video card does not support ROCm

https://github.com/benoitsteiner/tensorflow-opencl

or

https://github.com/hughperkins/tf-coriander